# Can we use `export default` and `module.exports` at same time?

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to use `export default` and `module.exports` in the same file.

/******** Exports ********/

```
export default function () { ... };

module.exports = {
    A,
    B,
    C
};
```

How to import them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure it's not possible - a default export is basically the same thing as the object (or other expression) you assign to `module.exports`. Better to use just one syntax style (`module.exports` or `export`) consistently. If you're looking to export a default *and* export other things as well, consider using named exports instead, with `export` syntax:

```
// define A, B, C
export default function() { ... };
export { A, B, C };
```

and import with, for example

```
import fn, { A } from './module';
```

Comment: So `export default { A, B, C };` and `module.exports = { A, B, C };` are same?

Comment: AFAIK, when something is trying to import that module, yes - in both cases, the module has exported an object containing properties A, B, and C. (both export syntaxes work with `import` and `require`)

Comment: Thanks, But how to import bot statement?

Comment: Like the answer says, use named exports with `export` syntax: `export { A, B, C };` and then `import fn, { A } from './module';`