# How to use both module.exports and exports.default

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, export

Is it possible that a module can be imported both like this,

```js
import foo from 'foo';
```

and like this?

```js
const foo = require('foo');
```

If so, the syntax of the export could look something like that:

```js
const foo = 'a string to export';
exports.default = foo;
module.exports = foo;
```

But according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54900077/9515617), it's an incorrect syntax.

I ask this question because I came across a module that use this syntax and is bugged (`import foo from 'foo'` makes `foo` be `undefined` but `const foo = require('foo')` is fine).
But in the other hand, the [add-module-exports plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports) adds this syntax deliberately, so I'm a bit lost.

---

EDIT:

I found a way, but it's a bit hacky and it induces a circular reference, so I wouldn't say that it's the answer:

```js
module.exports = foo;
module.exports.default = foo;
```

Comment: I think `exports.default` is a babel thing? It's got to be an interoperability issue for your platform

Comment: `exports.default` works fine on its own. `module.exports` works fine on its own. It's both combined that doesn't work. Also, I'm using Node 13.2.0

Comment: As far as I understand it, node.js allows you to import cjs modules into es6 modules using the module syntax. There's nothing i can find on the documentation about `exports.default`.

Comment: I tough `exports.default = foo` was the standard way convert the ES6 `export default foo` syntax to a CommonJS syntax. Babel use it but it's not the only one, the TypeScript compiler also does this.